# Smoothing out contourplot in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I am trying to plot a simple contour plot (in gnuplot) for the [Himmelblau's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himmelblau%27s_function) using the following code :

```
f(x,y)=(((x**2)+(y)-11)**2)+(((x)+(y**2)-7)**2)
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
set contour base
set cntrparam level discrete 13.59085,25,50,100,150,300,500,1000
set table 'cont.dat'
splot f(x,y)
unset table
reset
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
unset key
p './cont.dat' w l lt -1
```

I get the following plot result:
[image: result.img]

There are a few problems with the plot which I wish to eliminate:

1. It shows some horizontal lines in the plot, I don't know why. How can I remove the horizontal lines?
2. The contour lines are not too smooth. How can I improve there smoothness?

I feel that both the above problems are connected but can't figure out how. Can you please help me understand and hopefully eliminate the problems?

EDIT 1 : I found the answer to question-2, i.e. improving smoothness. I could do it by increasing the `isosample`. But I still get a lot of horizontal lines as shown in figure below.
[image: smoother_contourlines.img]

But how to remove these horizontal lines? I just want the contour lines for the levels specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can plot only the contour lines: You must use `unset surface`, which plots only the contour lines, and view the plot from above with `set view map`. See also the [2D contour projection plot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/contours.html) from the gnuplot demos.

Smoothing can be achieved with `set isosamples`, but in some way also using e.g. `set cntrparam bspline` and similar.

So your script becomes:

```
f(x,y)=(((x**2)+(y)-11)**2)+(((x)+(y**2)-7)**2)
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]

set contour base
set cntrparam level discrete 13.59085,25,50,100,150,300,500,1000

set isosamples 250
unset surface
set view map
set key out

splot f(x,y)
```

With the result (using 4.6.3):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve both the problems. The solution to Problem-2 I already shared in the edit-1 of question.

For Problem-1, i.e. removing the IsoLines from the contour plot, I should have left the initial blocks of data int he `cont.dat` files which contain the data for the isolines. Instead, I should have plotted from the Data Block 250 onwards (first 250 blocks of data were from IsoLines because of `set isosample 250,250` command).